# Trying to fetch the value from 2 tables in codeigniter code

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Working on 2 tables (Homework & Deliveries). I am able to fetch the value of "homework_code" from Deliveries Table. Now same field is there in the Homework table as well without primary key.
I am trying to fetch the value of "title" field from a table "homework". both tables has common value of student_id. The code is :

```
<?php
$invoices = $this->db->get_where('deliveries', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->result_array();
foreach($invoices as $row2): ?>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $row2['homework_code'];?>
</td>
<td>
<?php echo $this->db->get_where('homework' , array('homework_code'=>'class_id'))->row()->title; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row2['title'];?>
     </td> 
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Your Question above, if Your Database Structure is like that then use:-

**Homework Table :-**

```
title
student_id
```

**Deliveries Table :-**

```
homework_code  
student_id
```

**then Change this:-**

```
<td>
<?php echo $this->db->get_where('homework' , array('homework_code'=>'class_id'))->row()->title; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $row2['title'];?>
</td>
```

**to this way:-**

```
<td>
<?php
$student_id = $row2['student_id'];
$homework = $this->db->get_where('homework',array('student_id'=>$student_id))->result_array(); 
echo $homework['title'];
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based by your code above, you can use Controller like this

```
public function get()
    {
        $data = $this->db->get_where('deliveries', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->result_array();
        $fetch['fetchdata'] = $this->db->get_where('homework', array($data[0]['homework_code'] => 'class_id'))->result_array();

        $this->load->view('yourview', $fetch);
    }
```

and get the out put by putting this on View :

```
<?= $fetchdata[0][title] ?>
```

However the result_array() function will producing array for the result even it was only one though